# How to mock SQS with moto to test invoking Lambda function using boto3. ClientError raised on GetQueueUrl

Tags: python, aws-lambda, automated-tests, moto

I am trying write some integration tests for the Lambda function which connects to an already created SQS Queue. I need to mock this SQS connection.
I am not sure if mocking will work since I use boto3 Lambda.invoke() along with [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html) - `sam local start-lambda` to invoke the Lambda function in pytest function.

pytest sample code

```
def connect_to_lambda_client(running_locally: bool = True):
    if running_locally:
        lambda_client = boto3.client(
            "lambda",
            region_name="us-west-2",
            endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:3001",
            use_ssl=False,
            verify=False,
            config=botocore.client.Config(
                signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED,
                read_timeout=20,
                retries={"max_attempts": 0},
            ),
        )
    else:
        lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")
    return lambda_client

@mock_sqs
def test_lambda_function():
    client = connect_to_lambda_client()
    lambda_response = client.invoke(FunctionName="ListPersonFunction")
    
    assert lambda_response.get("statusCode") == 200
```

sample lambda function

```
QUEUE_NAME = os.getenv('SQSLOGQUEUENAME')

client = boto3.resource('sqs')
queue = client.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=QUEUE_NAME) #raises ClientError

queue.send_message(
            MessageBody=_record,
            MessageGroupId=self.group_id,
            MessageDeduplicationId=self.deduplication_id
        )
```

Traceback of client error

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetQueueUrl operation: The secu    
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) _make_api_callarams)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moto only mocks requests made within the Python-context that it is executed in. It has no way of knowing what happens within SAM.

You could use MotoServer in this case. It offers the same functionality as Moto, but runs as a standalone server.

To start the server:

```
pip install moto[server,all]
moto_server -H 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
```

Creating/retrieving the queue can be done by providing the endpoint URL, exactly how you also connect to SAM:

```
sqs_client = boto3.client(
    "sqs",
    region_name="us-west-2",
    endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:5000",
)
```

Because this Server runs separately from everything, you can connect to it from within your Python-program (to create the queue) and from within SAM (to retrieve the queue).